# Не работает часть функционала бота на Discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

проблема такова: При запуске всех функций кроме выдачи роли по реакции всё работает отлично и если запускать исключительно с выдачей ролей по реакции всё хорошо,но как только нужно заставить это работать вместе(для этого я прописую intents) бот перестаёт считывать команды,но роли выдаёт и забирает.
Я не очень понимаю в программировании и делаю этого бота по инструкциям на ютубе,объясните пожалуйста как решить эту проблему и в чем конкретно дело.

````
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord import utils
import youtube_dl
import os
import config

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client)) #Просто проверка на запуск
    await  client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game('?help'))
#Join and leave

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    global voice
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice=get(client.voice_clients,guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f'Бот присоеденился к каналу: {channel}')

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice=get(client.voice_clients,guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
        await ctx.send(f'Бот отключился от канала: {channel}')

#Play
@client.command(pass_context=True, brief="Эта песня будет играть следующей  ' [url]'", aliases=['pl'])
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Подождите пока текущая песня закончится или используйте команду  '?stop'")
        return
    await ctx.send("Подождите немного музыка обрабатывается ...")
    print("Someone wants to play music let me get that ready for them...")
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            name = file
            os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
    voice.volume = 100
    voice.is_playing()
    song_name = name.rsplit('-',2)
    await ctx.send(f'Сейчас проигрывается эта композиция: {song_name[0]}')
@client.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    "Ставит аудио на паузу"
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients,guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause()
        await ctx.channel.send(f'{ctx.author.name} Ставит трэк на паузу')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send(f'Музыка уже на паузе')

@client.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    "Воспроизводит аудио"
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients,guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_paused():
        voice.resume()
        await ctx.channel.send(f'{ctx.author.name} Воспроизводит трэк')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send(f'Музыка уже играет')

@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
            "Воспроизводит аудио"
            voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
            if voice.is_playing():
                voice.stop()
                await ctx.channel.send(f'{ctx.author.name} Выключает музыку')
            else:
                await ctx.channel.send(f'Сейчас ничего не играет')

#очистка чата
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def clear(ctx, amount : int):
    await  ctx.channel.purge(limit = 100)

#Ошибки при вводе не верных значений и недостатке прав
@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send (f'{ctx.author.name}, обязательно укажите кол-во удаляемых сообщений!')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name},у вас недостаточно прав!')

#очистка комманд
@client.command()
async def hello( ctx, amount = 1):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = amount )
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f'Hello { author.mention }' )

#Кик
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def kick( ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None ):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1)
    await member.kick(reason = reason)
    await ctx.send(f'kick user {member.mention}')

@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name},у вас недостаточно прав!')

#Бан
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True)
async def ban(ctx,member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit= 1)
    await member.ban(reason = reason)
    await ctx.send(f'ban user {member.mention}')
@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name},у вас недостаточно прав!')

#Help
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Навигация по командам')
    emb.add_field(name= '{}clear'.format( '?' ),value='Очистка чата')
    emb.add_field(name= '{}ban'.format( '?' ),value='Бан на сервере')
    emb.add_field(name= '{}kick'.format( '?' ),value='Кик с сервера')
    emb.add_field(name='{}user_mute'.format('?'), value='Мут')
    await ctx.send( embed=emb )

#Mute
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def user_mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name='Mute')
    await member.add_roles(mute_role)
    await ctx.send(f'У {member.mention},ограничение чата за нарушение правил!')

@user_mute.error
async def user_mute_error(ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name},у вас недостаточно прав!')

#Выдача ролей при подключении
@client.event
async def on_member_join( member ) :
   channel = client.get_channel(672423347174375435)
   role = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 830876511850201119 )
   await member.add_roles( role )
   await channel.send(emb = discord.Embed(description=f'Пользователь ``{member.name}``, присоеденился к нам!',color= 0x0c0c0c ))
#Выдача ролей по реакциям

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
            channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)  # получаем объект канала
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # получаем объект сообщения
            member = utils.get(message.guild.members,
                               id=payload.user_id)  # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

            try:
                emoji = str(payload.emoji)  # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
                role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])  # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

                if (len([i for i in member.roles if i.id not in config.EXCROLES]) <= config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                    print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))

            except KeyError as e:
                print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
            except Exception as e:
                print(repr(e))

    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)  # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members,
                           id=payload.user_id)  # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji)  # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])  # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))

        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
client = MyClient(intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.run(config.TOKEN)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это происходит потому что у вас отдельные команды привязаны к объекту `client`, который вы объявляете в этой строке:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)
```

А функции `async def on_raw_reaction_add()` и `async def on_raw_reaction_remove()`
находятся внутри класса `class MyClient(discord.Client)`

И в самом конце, вы **переопределяете** объект `client` и задаете новое значение:

```
client = MyClient(intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

В итоге вы запускаете только отдельный класс этой строчкой:

```
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Соответственно, запущенный в отдельном классе бот имеет только 2 функции-события для работы с реакциями. А бот с остальными командами вообще не запущен.

---

Чтобы избавиться от проблемы, нужно вынести функции класса в общий код и запускать одного цельного бота `discord.ext.commands.Bot()`.

**Этот код должен работать:**

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord import utils
import youtube_dl
import os
import config

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client)) #Просто проверка на запуск
    await  client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game('?help'))
#Join and leave

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    global voice
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice=get(client.voice_clients,guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f'Бот присоеденился к каналу: {channel}')

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice=get(client.voice_clients,guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
        await ctx.send(f'Бот отключился от канала: {channel}')

#Play
@client.command(pass_context=True, brief="Эта песня будет играть следующей  ' [url]'", aliases=['pl'])
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Подождите пока текущая песня закончится или используйте команду  '?stop'")
        return
    await ctx.send("Подождите немного музыка обрабатывается ...")
    print("Someone wants to play music let me get that ready for them...")
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            name = file
            os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
    voice.volume = 100
    voice.is_playing()
    song_name = name.rsplit('-',2)
    await ctx.send(f'Сейчас проигрывается эта композиция: {song_name[0]}')
@client.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    "Ставит аудио на паузу"
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients,guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause()
        await ctx.channel.send(f'{ctx.author.name} Ставит трэк на паузу')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send(f'Музыка уже на паузе')

@client.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    "Воспроизводит аудио"
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients,guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_paused():
        voice.resume()
        await ctx.channel.send(f'{ctx.author.name} Воспроизводит трэк')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send(f'Музыка уже играет')

@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
            "Воспроизводит аудио"
            voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
            if voice.is_playing():
                voice.stop()
                await ctx.channel.send(f'{ctx.author.name} Выключает музыку')
            else:
                await ctx.channel.send(f'Сейчас ничего не играет')

#очистка чата
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def clear(ctx, amount : int):
    await  ctx.channel.purge(limit = 100)

#Ошибки при вводе не верных значений и недостатке прав
@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send (f'{ctx.author.name}, обязательно укажите кол-во удаляемых сообщений!')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name},у вас недостаточно прав!')

#очистка комманд
@client.command()
async def hello( ctx, amount = 1):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = amount )
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f'Hello { author.mention }' )

#Кик
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def kick( ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None ):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1)
    await member.kick(reason = reason)
    await ctx.send(f'kick user {member.mention}')

@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name},у вас недостаточно прав!')

#Бан
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True)
async def ban(ctx,member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit= 1)
    await member.ban(reason = reason)
    await ctx.send(f'ban user {member.mention}')
@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name},у вас недостаточно прав!')

#Help
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Навигация по командам')
    emb.add_field(name= '{}clear'.format( '?' ),value='Очистка чата')
    emb.add_field(name= '{}ban'.format( '?' ),value='Бан на сервере')
    emb.add_field(name= '{}kick'.format( '?' ),value='Кик с сервера')
    emb.add_field(name='{}user_mute'.format('?'), value='Мут')
    await ctx.send( embed=emb )

#Mute
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def user_mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name='Mute')
    await member.add_roles(mute_role)
    await ctx.send(f'У {member.mention},ограничение чата за нарушение правил!')

@user_mute.error
async def user_mute_error(ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name},у вас недостаточно прав!')

#Выдача ролей при подключении
@client.event
async def on_member_join( member ) :
   channel = client.get_channel(672423347174375435)
   role = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 830876511850201119 )
   await member.add_roles( role )
   await channel.send(emb = discord.Embed(description=f'Пользователь ``{member.name}``, присоеденился к нам!',color= 0x0c0c0c ))
#Выдача ролей по реакциям

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
        channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)  # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members,
                           id=payload.user_id)  # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji)  # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])  # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

            if (len([i for i in member.roles if i.id not in config.EXCROLES]) <= config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
            else:
                await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))

        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)  # получаем объект канала
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # получаем объект сообщения
    member = utils.get(message.guild.members,
                       id=payload.user_id)  # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

    try:
        emoji = str(payload.emoji)  # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
        role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])  # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

        await member.remove_roles(role)
        print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))

    except KeyError as e:
        print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))

client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Comment: Спасибо,большое за помощь,я частично понял свою ошибку,и кажется заметил где конкретно всё ломалось.За информацию  еще раз спасибо.